# How to serialize a type that inherits WPF's Paragraph?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

I sub-classed the `WPF`'s `Paragraph` as follows, and now I want to serialize and deserialize it, including the additional data.

`xamlString = XamlWriter.Save(_richTextBox.Document);` doesn't do the trick - the extended data is omitted.

There's is way to tell the `XamlWriter` to include this extra data ?

Here is the extended data:

```
[ContentProperty("Inlines")]
public class ExParagraph : Paragraph
{
    public ParagraphMetaData MetaData = new ParagraphMetaData();
}

[ContentProperty("Inlines")]
public class ParagraphMetaData {
    private Guid _updaterParagraphUniqueId;

    public Guid UpdaterParagraphUniqueId {
        get { return _updaterParagraphUniqueId; }
        set {
            _updaterParagraphUniqueId = value;
            IsUpdaterParagraph = value != default(Guid);
        }
    }

    public bool IsUpdaterParagraph { get; private set; }
    public string Name;
    public bool DoNotToggleColor;
}
```

### Edit - solution:

Thanks to responders: the fields must be r/w properties

In addition, the `[ContentProperty("Inlines")]` was the root problem - it prevented the serialization of the sub-classed `Paragraph`

Comment: I see a curious mixture of plain properties and public fields. Have you tried what happens with a Dependency Property ?  What is the class name inside the produced XAML?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, yes, got it: all fields must be r/w properties, and the `[ContentProperty("Inlines")]` must be removed too... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are not serialized, only properties. They also must be read-write properties, not read-only. This post is pretty old but most of the information still applies:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/16/xamlwriter.aspx

Edit: also read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx for additional information.

Comment: yes, got it: all fields must be r/w properties, and the `[ContentProperty("Inlines")]` must be removed too... Thanks!